# Why does it not work to send a parameter in a subroute with router-deprecated in my angular2 project?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to set up a routing system in my angular2 app, but cannot send parameters. Have checked various tutorials for router-deprecated, and it seems that this code is right, but I still get errors.

**app.component.ts**

```
    <li id="whatsup" (click)="loadField('whatsup')" ><a [routerLink]="['Whats']"> Whatsup?</a></li>
...
    @RouteConfig([
        {path: '/whatsup/...', name: 'Whats', component: Whatsup, useAsDefault:'true'},
```

**whatsup.component.ts**

```
<li class="list-group-item"><a [routerLink]="['Tod', {day:'today'}]">Today</a></li>
...
@RouteConfig([
    {path:"/whichday/:day", component: Today, name:'Tod'}
```

**today.component.ts**

```
import {RouteParams} from "@angular/router-deprecated";

...

    export class Today implements OnInit{
        list:string;
        day:string;

        constructor(private _routeParams: RouteParams){}
        constructor(private _http: Http){}

        ngOnInit():any {
            this.day = this._routeParams.get('day');

...
```

I get this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:14:68 browser_adapter.js:86
>   EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:14:68 browser_adapter.js:77:13
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Route generator for 'day' was not included in parameters passed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok two ways to navigate one from the `[routerLink]` attribute and one programmatically with `(click)` event

**- The `[routerLink]` attribute:**

define the `:day` value in your `whatsup.component.ts` file, ex:

```
private today: string = 'sunday';
```

and in the template

```
<a [routerLink]="['Tod', {day: today }]"></a>
<!-- notice today written without quotation mark -->
```

note that your `@RouteConfig([])` should be configured only in the `app.component.ts` file since it's the root for everything

**- The programmatical solution (as seen in the documentation):**

in your template

```
<div (click)="gotoDetail(day)"></div>
```

in your `component.ts` file

```
gotoDetail(day: string) {
  let link = ['Tod', { id: id }];
  this.router.navigate(link);
}
```

PS: Try to work with one `constructor` it's a better practice

hope my solution helps!

Comment: This should also work from a template. It's valid `routerLink` syntax

Comment: If you have child routes `@RouteConfigs()` on other components is valid as well.

Comment: Bro I'm trying to give the best practice! it will make you development easier @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Using child routes is not against best practices.